# rails 3 won't autoload one helper from another helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autoload, helper

I have a custom helpers path lib/helpers, which i autoload by adding following in application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(classes helpers).map{|dir| "#{Rails.root}/lib/#{dir}"}
```

One of the helpers, VideoHelper, utilizes FileHelper in one of it's methods:

```
class VideoHelper

 def my_method
  FileHelper::my_method
 end

end
```

While testing VideoHelper's my_method with rspec, all calls to FileHelper::my_method fail with:

```
NameError:
   uninitialized constant VideoHelper::FileHelper
```

Tests succeed if i add call to FileHelper before VideoHelper class declaration:

```
FileHelper
class VideoHelper

 def my_method
  FileHelper::my_method
 end

end
```

Do i have to require FileHelper in VideoHelper even when it's declared in autoload_paths?

Answer (score 0):

Found a must-read on the topic:

http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/